# Can I set mouse-wheel scroll speed to match animation speed with skrollr.js

Tags: javascript, html, parallax, skrollr

I'm using skrollr.js for the first time to mock up a prototype parallax site, however while I can find many options to adjust and smoothen the animation from links (like the menu) the page looks pretty choppy when scrolling with the mouse.

I figured the nicest looking fix would be to slow the mouse wheel scroll to match the rest of the page, is this possible/the best solution?

This is a link to the mock up page:
http://teahouse.server105.com/indexv4.html

And this is my call for skrollr/initiate values:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.menu.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
    var s = skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: false,
            smoothScrolling: true,
            smoothScrollingDuration: 150

    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
            easing: 'swing',
            animate: true,
             duration: function(currentTop, targetTop){
                 return Math.abs(currentTop - targetTop) * 3;
             }

            });
}, 500);      
    </script>
```